# How to write code for multiple iteration until expect message in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Any suggestions please. Which controller need to use and how ? Little deep information

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Sampler which will run the request looking for the "message"
2. Create a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract the message (or indicator of presence of message) into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and add it a a child of the Sampler
3. Put everything under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and come up with a proper condition which resolves to `true` and becomes `false` when the "message" is in the response.